# How to pass values from android to unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Anyone know how to pass values from android application to Unity3D application?
I am using unity3D application as part of my android application, I am using 
Android SDK for developing android application.

Comment: Yes, but when running the android app I got the error like AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError in my log file

Comment: Do you please post your logcat